# How do I save a file to disk?

Tags: c#, file, save

Here is my controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase excelFile)
    {

        /*Somewhere here, I have to save the uploaded file.*/

        var fileName = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), excelFile.FileName);
        var connectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; data source={0}; Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;", fileName);

        var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [workSheetNameHere$]", connectionString);
        var ds = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(ds, "results");

        DataTable data = ds.Tables["results"];

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to save to disk?

Comment: excelFile is the uploaded file to the website. An .xlsx file. I need to save that file permanently to the hard drive. I'm guessing using the .InputStream property? But I'm confused as to how to do that.

Comment: If you're just wondering how to save excelFile, we don't need the rest of the code that is talking to the database - it's confusing.  Just provide the minimum amount of code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is one way of handling it, if you're receiving uploaded files.

```
string nameAndLocation = "~/UploadedFiles/" + hpf.FileName;
hpf.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(nameAndLocation));
```

Comment: I think he was asking about saving excelFile specifically.

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried `HttpPostedFileBase.SaveAs` method?

Comment: I didn't see that method. :) Just one question, where does this save the file if I only give it a file name to use?

Comment: If only the file name is specified, the current directory will be used as a location of the file. And you may prefer to use not the Directory.GetCurrentDirectory, but Server.MapPath to map some relative path in you web site to a physical path. Fo example, Server.MapPath(@"~/ExcelFiles/data.xls")

Answer (score 4):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase excelFile)
{
   /*Somewhere here, I have to save the uploaded file.*/

   var fileName = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), excelFile.FileName);

   excelFile.SaveAs(fileName );

   //...
}
```

When in doubt, look at the documentation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfilebase.saveas.aspx